# How does session.save_path secure and improve performance of your sessions?

Tags: php, session

I would like to know why do you improve security to your sessions if you change `session.save_path` from the default /tmp to a real directory in your home directory before public_html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Security:

If multiple applications write their sessions in the same directory, this can potentially allow a user to manipulate the content of its session, and bypass the security of an other application.

For example, if application A relies on `$_SESSION['is_admin']` to be set to true for admin users, and application B allows the user to set `$_SESSION['is_admin']` to true, then the user can become admin on application A.

Setting a `session.save_path` different to each application avoids this problem.

If you don't control the other applications running on the same server, you should either store the sessions in a directory that's not accessible by other application, or crypt the sessions so that other applications can't read and modify them.

See **[this slide](http://www.slideshare.net/ZendCon/lesser-known-security-problems-in-php-applications-presentation)** (starting at page 15).

The PHP suhosin patch / module **[can encrypt your session automatically](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/a_feature_list.html#session_protection)**.

#### Performance:

PHP has to periodically walk though all session in `session.save_path` in order to remove the expired sessions. Having too many session in this directory can degrade performance.

If you have a different `session.save_path` per application, you have less session in each session directory.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have only one application that makes use of sessions in my shared hosting. My question is why changing the path from /tmp to home/here (before public_html) improves security ? What I am saying comes from http://www.supernifty.com.au/blog/2008/04/19/php-sessions-on-shared-hosting-hack-3/ and other articles.

Comment: This is a shared host, so there is multiple applications running on the same server, and you don't control other applications. So you must put your sessions in a directory that's not accessible by the other applications; changing session.save_path allows exactly that.

Comment: Oh, now I get the point. To clear up my mind, changing the path from temp to your account prevents other shared owners (and only them) to mess up with your sessions ? Of course the folder will be before public_html. Is that right ?

Comment: Thats right, if other shared owners can't read and write this directory (and if they can't set their session.save_path to your own home directory).

Comment: What permissions does this folder have to have ? 644 ? Or because is before public_html it does not matter.

Comment: 700, but if all owners on the shared host are running as the same user they will still be able to access the folder. If that's the case, crypt the sessions.